# API returning a USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP error

Tags: docusignapi

I've built an API-based integration with DocuSign (using their PHP SDK), and am now at the point of deploying to the production server. I have reconfigured everything with the production integration key, public/private key pair, user and account IDs, endpoint URL, etc. replacing the demo ones. The OAuth portion of the conversation is working fine, and I get a valid token back. When I then try to send an envelope, I hit a USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP error, and cannot figure out why. As far as I can see, everything about the API user is the same between the demo and production systems.

I've [authorized the application](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) and made sure that it's in the list of "Applications with Access to DocuSign".

I have [enabled logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), but the only things that are showing up in there appear to be from my own navigation in the site, nothing related to the API calls at all.

Most of the documentation that I can find on this simply repeats the generic error text: "The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account." If I go to the account admin and look at the list of users, the one I'm expecting is right there, with DS Admin permission; not sure what else might be done to give them "membership". One mentioned not using SendOnBehalfOf, but I'm not, so I can't really remove that.

All the code is identical, just configuration that's changed. Not sure where else to look. Anybody have any suggestions for what to try?

FURTHER INFORMATION

I've tried the `getUserInfo` call in the SDK, passing the same access token I use for the other call. It returns successfully, showing that it is for the user I'm expecting, in the one group we have, on the production server. And yet, when I enable logging again, as this same user, there is still zero record in the resulting logs of any of this API activity.

Attempts to do things like list templates with the SDK fail with the same USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP error.

Using the Diagnostics API (again, through the SDK) to check logging status shows that it is NOT enabled (despite my enabling it in the UI), but can be enabled with a separate call. Subsequently attempting to use `listRequestLogs` in the SDK generates a 404 error, though the URL matches what's listed in the API documentation (`/v2/diagnostics/request_logs`). Not sure whether these findings confirm that I'm somehow logging onto the API and the UI with different users (even though the user name and internal ID match), or that there's some problem with the logging facility in DocuSign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turns out to be the URL I was using for API calls. I switched from `demo.docusign.net` in testing to `www.docusign.net` in live, but being in Canada we need to use `ca.docusign.net`. For those who find this later, you can get the correct base path to use from the `oauth/userinfo` endpoint, or the `getUserInfo()` call through the SDK (PHP SDK, at least; don't know what the analogous call would be in others).

Comment: yup, like I said, one of the five things (or six sometimes) that needs to be changed between demo and prod.

Comment: I had changed it, and even to something valid. Just not valid for our account. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things to consider:

1. API calls are made to an endpoint (URL) that contains the account # (either GUID or short form) in the url. Take a note of that number in the url.
2. Auth Token is a token for a specific user in a specific account.
3. UserId for the specific call. That is a specific user in the account.

If the user is not in the account, or there's a mismatch between #1 and #2 - you'll get this error. You must work with a single account and have it in all places as well as the user must be a member of this account.

Comment: Thanks! We only have one account, and two users in it. Both users have admin permissions. So I don't see how either user could *not* be a member of the account. And I've copied the user ID and account ID from the "API and Keys" page, replacing the working values from the same page in the demo site with the corresponding values from production.

Comment: aha, demo and production. Which one are you using? you cannot swap demo and production accounts. You have to change everything, the url, the numbers, including the token and key and RSA private key. 6 different things are different between demo and prod. did you change them all to the correct values?

Comment: All covered in the original post, I think. I'll edit it slightly to emphasize that. And as I said, the entire OAuth process works just fine, I get a valid token back from production. It's when I make the API call to send an envelope that the error occurs.

Comment: yes, the API call is using a url. Please provide the account number in that url

Comment: Yes, the account number is in the URL, and it's the one for our production account. When I use the demo URL with our demo account number, it works fine. When I use the production URL with our production account number, it fails.

Comment: so, when you switch between demo and production, do you change five different things? can you count and confirm you change:
accountId
userId
RSA Token
Auth URL
API URL

Comment: I was changing everything, yes, but had the wrong value for the base URL.

Comment: glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> I have enabled logging, but the only things that are showing up in there appear to be from my own navigation in the site, nothing related to the API calls at all.

Since the request logging is not showing your API activity, the problem is that the person you've logged in as on the web tool is not the same as the person (user id) that you've logged in as on your application.

Solution for OAuth Authorization Code authentication: double check that when your app is logging into DocuSign, you're using the account.docusign.com authentication server, not the account-d.docusign.com auth server. (Look at the URL in your browser during the login sequence.)

Solution for OAuth JWT authentication: re-check that the impersonated user id is from the production system and you're using the right authentication server

Comment: Confirmed that OAuth is using account.docusign.com to log in. And the details we're using for that login are those from the "API and Keys" page on the production site, so surely the login would fail if any of that wasn't correct.

Comment: Additional details added in the question about further results that confirm both the correct login and the lack of logging.